# Knight's open tour on 5X5 board

Tags: knight-tours

I'm trying to write a program that finds an open knight's tour on 5X5 board starting from every point. I So the question is does every point actually has a solution. I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31411487/knights-tour-on-a-5-x-5-board-start-from-any-square) that says that there is no solution when you start at any of the squares adjacent to a corner square. However when I run a program I get solutions only when I start in the points marked with k

```
 k| |k| |k
  |k| |k| 
 k| |k| |k
  |k| |k| 
 k| |k| |k
```

Comment: The very next answer says that tours only exist starting on a square the same color as a corner, agreeing with your diagram.

Comment: Thnx. I didn't quite get the coloring answer.